# Peut-on omettre « ne » avec « ni » ?

Tags: conjonctions, négation, coordination

Je lisais un texte et j'ai trouvé une phrase qui utilisait *ni* en négation et qui pourtant omettait le *ne*… Et je me demandais si c'était une faute ou bien si c'était voulu et valide.

Peut-on dans une phrase qui utilise le « ni » pour exprimer une séquence de négation omettre le « ne », ou est-il obligatoire? Par exemple :

> Il est ni grand, ni petit.

Ou

> Il n'est ni grand, ni petit

J'ai cherché des articles sur le sujet et n'est pas trouvé d'exemple vraiment clair. La BDL de [l'OQLF cite](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3905):

> Par ailleurs, la conjonction de coordination *ni* **peut** s’associer à l’adverbe de néga­tion *ne*; *ni* sert à coordonner deux éléments dans une phrase négative.

*(Tout gras est mien)*

De la façon que c'est écrit, cela à l'air plutôt conditionnel, mais je ne sais pas si c'est moi qui comprends mal le contexte.

Comment: Pour moi « ni » remplace « pas » quand on veut coordonner deux éléments négatifs. « Il n'est pas grand et il n'est pas petit » → « il n'est ni grand ni petit. » Donc je le traite de la même façon que « pas ». Théoriquement le « ne » de « ne...pas » est obligatoire mais pratiquement il est souvent omis en langage familier surtout à l'oral. Je dirais la même chose de « ni » dans l'exemple que tu donnes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On peut omettre le *ne* à l'oral en langage familier, mais ce n'est pas spécifique à l'utilisation de *ni*. Je ne vois pas de différence entre

> Il (n')est ni grand, ni petit.
>   Il (n')est pas grand ni petit.
>   Il (n')est pas grand.

La phrase de la BDL que tu cites dit que l'on peut utiliser la conjonction *ni* avec *ne*, après les passages qui présentent les autres formes de négation (adverbes comme *pas*, pronoms comme *personne*, adjectifs comme *aucun*).

Comment: « Il n’est pas grand ni petit » s’utilise ?

Comment: @Édouard Beaucoup moins que « ni grand ni petit », mais on peut le dire. Cela dit c'est vrai qu'en général on dira « ni … ni … », parce que les adjectifs sont sur le même plan.